# Slash and Escape Problems in C#

Tags: c#, excel, escaping, slash

I wanna write some data to Excel in C# with COM, but I got a problem saving. Let's see the code:

1. ```
   workSheet.SaveAs("c:/users/amare/sub.xls");
   ```

   The code above will cause an error:

   > "Microsoft Excel can't open the file c://users/amare/sub.xls."

   But the code below works fine:
2. ```
   workSheet.SaveAs("c:\\users/amare/sub.xls");
   ```
3. ```
   workSheet.SaveAs(@"c:\users\amare\sub.xls");
   ```

Now I'm quite confused about this situation. I know 2) and 3) are absolutely right, but I'm used to writing code like 1):

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:/users/amare/desktop/file.txt");
sw.WriteLine("foo-bar");
sw.close();
```

This always works fine. So I want to know why it does not this time. Apparently C# escapes the path incorrectly in 1).

Comment: "c:/users" is _not_ a valid Windows path.

Comment: if fire this path "c:/users" from run it works so it is a valid path

Comment: I personnaly hate it when forward slashes are used for local paths. Local paths - back slashes. Web paths - forward slashes.

Comment: @HatSoft - `WorkSheet.SaveAs()` disagrees with you on this point. And it kind of has the last word here.

Comment: Not that it's what you are asking for, but maybe you'd want to consider using the System.IO.Path class when dealing with file paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `workSheet.SaveAs()` does its own validation and fix-up of the path. So you are (rightfully) being punished for using an invalid format. That format is usually accepted but 'usually' is not the same as 'always'.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your path and sure, it fails with a message stating the path is not valid or is not writable. I have also tried to write the file inside the Documents subfolder (where the write permission is granted) but the same error appears again. So it is definitively a problem inside the parser of the Excel interop. I think that, in windows, you should avoid this path separator.

If you use [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) defined prefixing the string with the `@` char

```
workSheet.SaveAs(@"c:\users\amare\sub.xls");
```

all works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reproducing the problem. I'll use the @ char.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, you are right as usual, but the error message given by `SaveAs` was a bit unclear. So I have just tried to test if it was something connected to permission required to write in the root of the user folder.